# How to get multiple category lines with bar chart in Power Bi?

Tags: powerbi, data-visualization, reporting, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

Sample Data.

```
CompanyA,2019-01-01,29000
CompanyA,2019-02-01,35000
CompanyA,2019-03-01,43000
CompanyA,2019-04-01,27000
CompanyA,2019-05-01,45000
CompanyA,2019-06-01,21000
CompanyA,2019-07-01,26000
CompanyA,2019-08-01,27285
CompanyA,2019-09-01,26035
CompanyA,2019-10-01,24785
```

**Expected Output.**

My Boss has asked me to show sale trend by companies and month. but he wants it to be shown like below.

1. X axis should have Month Names
2. Bar lines should tell overall sales amount by month.
3. multiple lines should represent company sales amount.

i have achived this output by replacing 2 charts on each other (hidden one background).

[image: Sample Image]

First i have taken a **CLUSTERED COLUMN CHART** and place a Line chart on it with hidden background.

[Sample File](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvZUqpXgHxIVz2rV7sTPR1G8XQmn?e=wK3LXC)

But for me this is just an adhoc solution and One more problem is that both chart's y axis doesn't match.
seeking for a good solution on this. either another good chart to represent this kind of data or how to achive it any other way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create measures for individual company, if number of companies is not a big number, and then put them in "Line values" to achieve the same result as above.

So For ex, if you have 5 companies in the data then create 5 different measures like below
CompanyA = calculate(sum(sales), filter(tbl, [company] = "CompanyA"))
like the above ex create measures for other 4 companies also

Comment: Hi @swapnil  ! Thanks for your reply.
I've almost 2000 companies in Company Column. 
any other solution?